# Scrapy only outputs '['

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am building a web crawler using scrapy that just takes all reddit links of the front page. When I try to put it into a json folder all I get is '['.

Here is my spider.

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from redditScrape.items import RedditscrapeItem


class RedditSpider(Spider):
    name = "redditScrape"
    allowed_domains = ["reddit.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.reddit.com/r/all"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="entry unvoted lcTagged"]/p[@class="title"]')

        for title in titles:
            item = RedditscrapeItem()
            item['title'] = title.xpath('/a[@class="title may-blank loggedin  srTagged imgScanned"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Whenever I run the xpath query in my google chrome console I get the result im looking for.

[image]

Any idea why my scraper wont output correctly?

This is the command I am using to execute:

```
scrapy crawl redditScrape -o items.json -t json
```

Comment: Where do you see `title may-blank loggedin  srTagged imgScanned`? That does not exist at all, `srTagged` is not even in the source. I am not sure what you are looking at but it is not the same as what I can see in my browser looking at `https://www.reddit.com/r/all`

Comment: When I inspect element on reddit.com/r/all it has that in the class tag. @PadraicCunningham

Comment: I am looking at it now, it is nowhere to be seen! I see `title may-blank loggedin`, try     `'./a[@class="title may-blank loggedin"]'`

Comment: Hmmm, I think part of it may be because I have the RES installed which may me manipulating the results. @PadraicCunningham

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am trying to grab all titles of submitted posts on r/all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the problem is but I will have a go at what I see wrong in your code.

- First off, I don't know what the `-t` argument is but I suspect you wanted to reassure that the output was a json file. You don't need to. `-o items.json` is enough. `scrapy crawl redditScrape -o items.json`
- You don't need to declare `Selector` you can just as well do `titles = response.xpath('//div[@class="entry unvoted lcTagged"]/p[@class="title"]')`. This is not an error as much as it is a quality of life improvement.
- The second xpath is shady to say the least `item['title'] = title.xpath('a[@class="title may-blank loggedin  srTagged imgScanned"]/text()').extract_first()`

Whenever an item is successfully yield, scrapy will add it to the output file in runtime.

Edit.

You can simply use this xpath `//p[@class="title"]/a/text()` to get all the titles from the front page. In your code it will look something like this

```
    for title in response.xpath('//p[@class="title"]/a'):
        item = RedditscrapeItem()
        item['title'] = title.xpath('text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

Comment: Why do you say my second xpath is shady?

Comment: When you put `/` at the start of xpath you are looking for the root element which in this case there isn't one

Comment: I removed the / at the beginning of the xpath. If you connect the 2 strings together it works in the google chrome console however either way it doesn't work in scrapy.

Comment: If you print the variable `titles` does it output `None`?

Comment: I get '[]' when i print the titles variable

Comment: I also tried using this xpath `//div[@class="entry unvoted lcTagged"]/p[@class="title"]` in chrome and it returned no results, what element are you looking for? every title text of reddit threads?

Comment: This answer worked for me. Thank you so much @Rafael

Answer (score 1):

This css selector will get all the titles:

```
In [13]: response.css("a.title.may-blank::text").extract()
Out[13]: 
[u'TIL of a millionaire who announced he would bury his Bentley for his afterlife. After lots of negative reaction, he revealed the publicity stunt about organ donations. "People bury things that are much more valuable then cars and nobody seems to care".',
 u'Dog thinks he has a bunch of friends',
 u'Sewage leak at a movie theater. Looks like black tile.',
 u'3:48 am "Hydraulic Press"',
 u'I told her it was for their protection...',
 u'Long visits to nature linked to improved mental health, study finds',
 u"Vladimir Putin Says Brexit Caused by British Politicians 'Arrogance'",
 u"World's smallest man dancing with his pet cat. 26th October 1956.",
 u'I am Sue Sullivan and Reddit saved my sauce and rub company, Hot Squeeze. Tomorrow, I\u2019m heading to Wal-Mart for my last, big pitch for distribution. Whatever happens, I wanted to say thank you for all your support and AMA! Helping me out with this AMA will be Lawrence Wu, the founder WUJU hot sauce!',
 u"Cartoons made me think dog catchers were super common, but now I'm pretty sure they don't even exist",
 u'Zarya ultimate chain kill',
 u'Shaqiri scores vs Poland to make it 1-1',
 u'Mythbusters, during their later seasons',
 u"'Why not Texit?': Texas nationalists look to the Brexit vote for inspiration",
 u'Ken M on Hitler',
 u'Skill, pure skill',
 u'My girlfriend paints things. This is a pair of Vans she is currently working on.',
 u'I made a magnet wall to display my PS4 steelbook game collection!',
 u'HuffPo in 2008: "Muslims appear to be far more concerned about perceived slights to their religion than about atrocities committed daily in its name"',
 u"It's been almost 3 years since the removal of the Rose block. Never forget.",
 u"Xherdan Shaqiri's insane bicycle kick goal vs. Poland",
 u"US Customs wants to collect social media account names at the border: 'Please enter information associated with your online presence'",
 u'How was the cameraman for Finding Dory able to hold his breath for the entire filming?',
 u'Star Guardian Urgot',
 u'I made some doorstops! (Not as lame as it sounds)']
```

To add the item, your code just needs:

```
In [9]: for text in response.css("a.title.may-blank::text").extract():
   ...:     item['title']  = text
   ...:     yield item
```